# Is it best way to data binding with [innerHTML], angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript, data-binding

My problem is that in angular 4 there are few ways to data bind with HTML to TS like `{{myText}}`, `[]`, `()` and other than those we can use `[innerHTML]="myText"`

**what is the best way to bind simple variable to HTML among {{}}, [innerHTML] ?**

Comment: they are used for different purposes.  expression binding (`{{}}`) outputs raw text, while `[innerHTML]` outputs HTML formatted text.  What is "best" depends on what the variable contains.

Comment: if it is a just a text ?

Answer (score 3):

Try like this :

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlString"></div>
```

in typescript file :

```
htmlString: string = "Hello world"; <!-- if want to display string -->
htmlString: string = "<h1>Hello world</h1>"; <!-- if want to display html element -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind it with {{yourText}} is it is not containing any HTML markups

Bind it with [innerHTML] = "youtText" if it has any HTML markups